# Why array Index starts at 1 when passing range values to array

Tags: excel, vba

In this VBA program all I am trying to do is to pass an array from spreadsheet and add 1 to each of the array's cells. My problem is with the index of the array. when I start looping the array it doesnt 
work when I start the index from zero ( I get error subscript out of range) but it works perfectly when I start the array from 1. Why is that? (I thought that would be the case only I specify at the top *Option Base 1*)

```
Sub Passarray()
    Dim Array As Variant
    Dim i, j As Integer
    'Pass array and manipulate
    Vol = Range("Volatility")
    For i = 0 To 2
       For j = 0 To 2
          Vol(i, j) = 1+ Vol(i,j)
       Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but do you realise that i is not dimmed as an integer, but as a variant? In VBA you cannot chain declarations. You need to do `Dim i as Integer, j as Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

That wasn't the case when you pass *Range* to arrays based on my experience.
I don't know the specific reason behind, but [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) indicates that you cannot change this behavior.

> <sup>QUOTE: The array into which the worksheet data is loaded always has an lower bound (LBound) equal to 1, regardless of what Option Base directive you may have in your module. You cannot change this behavior.</sup>

What you can do is to utilize the use of *LBound/UBound* like this:

```
Vol = Range("Volatility")
For i = LBound(Vol, 1) To UBound(Vol, 1)
    For j = Lbound(Vol, 2) To Ubound(Vol, 2)
        '~~> do stuff here
        Vol(i, j) = 1 + Vol(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
```

If however your *Range* is just one column with several rows, you pass it to Array like this:

```
Vol = Application.Transpose(Range("Volatility"))
For i = LBound(Vol) To UBound(Vol)
    '~~> do stuff here
    Vol(i) = 1 + Vol(i)
Next
```

This way, you will produce one-D array instead of two-D array.
To iterate values you can use above or you can also use *For Each*:

```
Dim x As Variant '~~> dimension another variant variable
For Each x In Vol
    '~~> do stuff here
    x = 1 + x
Next
```